# Batch file to move files to folders named with year and month from modification date

Tags: sorting, date, batch-file, for-loop, move

I have thousands of files that need to be moved into folders named by the year and month in the modification date.  I've done this before with success, but for some reason it's failing as the main string value is not getting set.  Here's what I have:

A test folder with 3 files.  All files have VERY long names. such as:
LocalId=99a73-f852d-407907-98ce-4ab02dde5b41_SessionId=999999.flv

The above file name is representative of the files I am working with.

They exist in a folder: E:\backups\test

They are the ONLY items in this folder.

When I run the test command: for /f %a in ("E:\backups\test*.*") do set filedate=%~ta

The proper information is returned: set filedate=12/29/2014 12:44 PM

My batch file looks like this:

```
@rem ############################################################
@rem SETTING TIME AND DATE PARAMETERS FOR CREATION OF LOG FILES
set hr=%time:~0,2%
if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
set outFile=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
@rem ############################################################
@rem ############################################################
@rem SETTING PATHS FOR PROCESSING LOG FILES
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET dir=E:\backups\test
SET logDir=C:\scripts\logs
SET datesort=%logDir%\logfile.name.%outFile%.log
@rem ############################################################
@rem PARSING FILE MODIFIED DATE FOR YEAR AND MONTH
@rem CALLS PROCESS TO SET YEAR AND MONTH
@rem MOVES FILES INTO DATED FOLDERS
@rem ROBOCOPY TAKES CARE OF FOLDER CREATION AUTOMATICALLY
@rem SETS YEAR AND MONTH
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%dir%\*.flv" ') DO (
 SET "filedate=%%~ta"
  CALL :finddate
  robocopy "%dir%" /XX /r:10 %dir%\!year!!month!\ "!filedate!" /MOV >> %datesort%
)
GOTO sendmail
:finddate
SET year=%filedate:~6,4%
SET month=%filedate:~0,2%
GOTO :EOF
GOTO finddate
:sendmail
@rem ############################################################
@rem SENDING MAIL NOTIFICATION WITH LOG
<command for sending email notification>
```

What am I missing here to make this work?  I'm sure it's something simple.  Maybe I'm just too tired to pick up on it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the `!filedate!` parameter is supposed to do in the `robocopy` line.

Without a `/mindate:` switch (or whatever) then `!filedate!` will be taken as a filespec, and I'm guessing you don't have files named `"12/29/2014 12:44 PM"`- which, btw is the same as `%%~ta` (so why use !filedate!`?)

Comment: I'm not using date parameters in the Robocopy command.  !filedate! is the same as %filedate%. It's used in looping functions.

Comment: The `robocopy` line would then be resolved to `robocopy "E:\backups\test" /XX /r:10 E:\backups\test\201412\ "12/29/2014 12:44 PM" /MOV >> C:\scripts\logs\logfile.name.yyyymmdd_hhmm.log`. I believe that is not valid `robocopy` syntax as `"12/29/2014 12:44 PM"` is not a valid filemask.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I had an error in my logic as I was trying to use !filedate! instead of %%a.  I have corrected this so the full file name will be returned, which is what I wanted.  However, my main string value is still not being set.  This just proves that I was indeed too tired to see simple things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for metavariables without setting them to an environment variable.

Delayed expansion isn't needed.

```
@echo off
@rem ############################################################
@rem SETTING TIME AND DATE PARAMETERS FOR CREATION OF LOG FILES
set hr=%time:~0,2%
if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
set outFile=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
@rem ############################################################
@rem ############################################################
@rem SETTING PATHS FOR PROCESSING LOG FILES
SET dir=E:\backups\test
SET logDir=C:\scripts\logs
SET datesort=%logDir%\logfile.name.%outFile%.log
@rem ############################################################
@rem PARSING FILE MODIFIED DATE FOR YEAR AND MONTH
@rem MOVES FILES INTO DATED FOLDERS
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%dir%\*.flv" ') DO (
  for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=/\. " %%b in ("%%~ta") do (
     md "%dir%\%%c%%b" 2>nul
     move "%dir%\%%a" "%dir%\%%c%%b"
  )
)
@rem ############################################################
@rem SENDING MAIL NOTIFICATION WITH LOG
:: <command for sending email notification>
pause
```

Comment: this is a better solution that what I had. Mine was made for a network move, yours is better as it's suiting for the local move. I am getting an error on the dated folder name: move "LocalId=99a73-f852d-407907-98ce-4ab02dde5b41_SessionId=999999.flv" "E:\backups\test\%c%b"

Comment: Use `echo move "%dir%\%%a" "%dir%\%%c%%b" & pause` and see what is being generated.  What was the error message?

Comment: Investigated this a bit further.  It's only processing the first file and then stopping.  Here's the error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.  It appears to be having problems with the long and funky file names.  I'll play with it a bit more and see what can be done.

Comment: if you paste the info that the `echo` version  gives you then it will be easier to give you advice.  It should be straightforward for you to examine the directory\filenames to see what is wrong - such as a space in the wrong spot - or you added quotes someplace.

Comment: The result is: echo move "E:\backups\test\E:\backups\test\*.flv" "E:\backups\test\201405"   & pause.  %%a is returning the path to the file, which is odd.  changed echo move "%dir%\%%a" "%dir%\%%c%%b" & pause to echo move "%%a" "%dir%\%%c%%b" & pause, which eliminated the first part of the problem.  Now the result is: move "E:\backups\test\*.flv" "E:\backups\test\201405"   & pause which moves all the files into the first folder created.

Comment: My test shows that it works as it should.  Something must have been changed in the code.

Comment: Just to be sure there weren't any changes, I copied and pasted your above code into a new file and ran it.  Here is the output: c:\scripts>FOR /F "delims=" %a IN ('dir /b /a-d "E:\backups\test\*.flv" ') DO (for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=/\. " %b in ("%~ta") do (
md "E:\backups\test\%c%b"  2>nul  
 move "E:\backups\test\%a" "E:\backups\test\%c%b" 
) ) 

c:\scripts>(for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=/\. " %b in ("") do (
md "E:\backups\test\%c%b"  2>nul  
 move "E:\backups\test\SecurityId=00a73f85-2d80-4907-98ce-4ab02dde5b41_SessionId=108200.flv" "E:\backups\test\%c%b" 
) )

Comment: Too long to paste the entire thing and I don't see an option for attaching a file.  I only copied the command input and the first file in the loop.  The file name is showing up just fine.  The dates for creating the folders are not.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you are using to the bottom, in code blocks.  Drop me a note in this question when you have,